# moment js custom date format conversion is going wrong

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my angular 4 application I am am receiving the date input in the below format:
`"26-SEP-17 09.20.44.123000 AM"`, I need to convert this to `"Sep 26, 2017 9:20:44 AM"`. So I have used *momentjs* and the code is as shown below:

```js
var convertedDate = moment("26-SEP-17 09.20.44.123000 AM", 'DD-MMM-YY HH.mm.ss.SSS a').format('MMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss A');

console.log(convertedDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

But I am getting convertedDate as `"Sep 2, 2017 9:20:44 AM"`. I could not able to understand why I am getting the date as `Sep 2, 2017` instead `Sep 26, 2017`, even though the hours, min and sec are coming correctly.

Comment: `d` for **Day Name**
`D` for **Days of Month** ! At least you should check official docs first :)

Answer (score 1):

Use correct format `DD` instead of `d`

```js
var convertedDate = moment("26-SEP-17 09.20.44.123000 AM", 'DD-MMM-YY HH.mm.ss.SSS a').format('MMM DD, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
console.log(convertedDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `format('MMM d, YYYY h:mm:ss A')`,

make it `format('MMM DD, YYYY h:mm:ss A') //notice the 'd' become 'DD'`

your new code must be:

```
convertedDate = moment("26-SEP-17 09.20.44.123000 AM", 'DD-MMM-YY HH.mm.ss.SSS a').format('MMM DD, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```